# Xcode : shortcut for highlight feature

Tags: xcode, tooltip, code-folding

I recently started using Xcode for developing. It's pretty neat. By accident I  happened to see one of its features. The feature only highlights the block of code I am currently working on. Other codes are covered with light grey. I do not know how to get that effect again. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably hovered your mouse over the line number bar like this:

[image]

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/xcode-4-key-binding-for-focus-code-blocks-on-hover

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to the "focus ribbon" on the left side between the code and line numbers.

Refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Editing/Editing.html

(Figure 3-10)

Comment: I had no idea this was called focus ribbon, I actually went to take a screenshot and add the annotation :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Code Folding Focus**.

If you want to turn it **ON** or **OFF** as you please, do as follows in **Xcode/Preferences**:

[image: assigning custom key to code folding focus]

Then, assign the key of your fits.